# Optimization Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Update Android Studio 1.3 to 1.4, whereupon code Editor slowly work. Slowly there is a transition between the lines, long delay entering characters.
Advise how to solve this problem.

Comment: mac os x, windows or linux?

Comment: hardartcore, windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and also wasn't able to close Android Studio using button "Close". For that problem "Invalidate and Restart" helped too.